# Apply Discrete Cosine Transform to an Image

Tags: python, image-processing, signal-processing, dft, dct

I want to apply Discrete Cosine Transform to my image

```
import os.path
from PIL import Image

if __name__ == '__main__':
    image_counter = 1  
while True:      
    if not os.path.isfile('noise_images/' + str (image_counter) + '.png'):
        break
    print(image_counter)
    noise_image_path = 'noise_images/' + str(image_counter) + '.png'
    noise_image = Image.open(noise_image_path)  
    # Apply DCT to an image.

    image_counter = image_counter + 1
```

Comment: you can use `scipy.fftpack.dct`. More details [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.fftpack.dct.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at this [scipy.fftpack.dct](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.fftpack.dct.html)

The following is a sample code of using this:

```
import cv2
from scipy.fftpack import dct

def dct2(block):
    return dct(dct(block.T, norm='ortho').T, norm='ortho')

img = cv2.imread(filename)
img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
dctImage = dct2(img.astype(float))
```